# json traversing inside jsp

Tags: json, jsp, jstl

I want to traverse a `json` object inside my jsp using below code. But I am not getting the values. Please provide the required taglib.

```
<c:import var="dataJson" url="test.json"/>
<json:parse="${dataJson}" var="parsedJSON">
<li>
<label class="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.isRequired}">CAF_lastname</label>
<div class="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.tagType}">
    <input id="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.tagID}"
           name="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.tagName}"
           type="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.tagNameType}"
           maxlength="${parsedJSON.groupId}" 
           value="test"
           data-vgroup="${parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails.tagValidationGroup}">
    </input>
</div>
```

I have a json  like:

```
{
 "Section":{
    "groupId": "1",
    "groupName": "Personal Details",
    "SectionSatrtTagName":"Personal Details"
    "fieldDetails": 
        [
         {
         "isRequired":"required",
         "labelName":"First Name",
         "tagType":"input",
         "tagID":"firstname",
         "tagName":"firstname",
         "tagValueBindField":"fname",
         "tagMaxLength":30,
         "tagValidationGroup":"personal-details",
         "isTagVisible":true,
         "hiddenName":"",
         "hiddenId":"",
         "hiddenValue":"",
         "hiddenBindWidth":"",
         "isHrRequired":true,
         "data-dependendValue":"",
         "tagNameType":"text" 
        },
        {
         "isRequired":"required",
         "labelName":"Last Name",
         "tagType":"input",
         "tagID":"lastname",
         "tagName":"lastname",
         "tagValueBindField":"lname",
         "tagMaxLength":20,
         "tagValidationGroup":"personal-details",
         "isTagVisible":true,
         "hiddenName":"",
         "hiddenId":"",
         "hiddenValue":"",
         "hiddenBindWidth":"",
         "isHrRequired":true,
         "data-dependendValue":"",
         "tagNameType":"text" 
        }
       ]
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Field details is an array. You will need to reference the index of the 'fieldDetail' before you can access its properties.

For Example: parsedJSON.Section.fieldDetails[0].isRequired

Comment: Hi Ashley, this is not working. Do I need to use any taglib for this?